# Expanded Adjoint of se(3)

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, adjoint-operators

Follow up to this question about adjoint Matrix of se(3) Lie algebra: [Adjoint of se(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3488949/adjoint-of-se3/4473290#4473290)

I understand that the adjoint Matrix for Lie algebra is the derivative of the Lie group adjoint matrix, but does anyone know what would the lie algebra's expanded adjoint matrix be in terms of theta (1,2,3) and translational terms (Vx, Vy, Vz)?

Comment: Take the six matrices [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1799191/the-physical-significance-of-the-lie-algebra-of-se3) and compute $[G_i,G_j]=G_iG_j-G_jG_i$ for $1\le i\le j\le 6$. This gives the adjoint operators ${\rm ad}(G_i)$.

Comment: When you mention that [Gi,Gj] for 1 ≤ i ≤ j ≤ 6, are you saying that it is only for i ≤ j? I am not sure if that is a mistake, but it would make ad(G6) = 0.

Comment: No, but $[x_j,x_i]=-[x_i,x_j]$, so we may assume $i<j$. This is what I mean.

Comment: I am still a bit confused about the matrices I am supposed to get for the adjoint operators. What I understand is that from the six matrices, I would be getting 6 different ad(Gi). In that case, should I be summing each terms to get one matrix? 

For example, for ad(G1), would I find the sum of [G1, G1], [G1,G2], [G1,G3], [G1,G4], [G1,G5], and [G1,G6]?

Comment: Indeed, for a basis $(g_1,\ldots ,g_6)$ you obtain six matrices ${\rm ad}(g_1),\ldots {\rm ad}(g_6)$. Recall that ${\rm ad}(x)(y)=[x,y]$. Then, for $x=r_1e_1+\cdots +r_6e_6$ you obtain ${\rm ad}(x)=r_1{\rm ad}e_1+\cdots +r_6{\rm ad}(e_6)$. This is linear algebra. For details, see any post here about adjoint matrices, for example [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600009/how-to-determine-the-matrix-of-adjoint-representation-of-lie-algebra).